# awk to count and rename symbol in field

Tags: awk

I am trying to `count` a `symbol` (-) in `$5` (ref) and output that symbol renamed and the count using `awk`.  The input file is tab-delimited and the `awk` below is close, but outputs extra data with incorrect counts and I'm not sure how to fix it.  Thank you :).

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {printf "Category\tCount\n" } $5 ~ /-/ {printf "indel" } {a[$5]++} END { for (i in a) {printf "%s\t\t%s\n",i , a[i] }}' input
```

**input**

```
Index   Mutation Call   Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    ExonicFunc.refGene  Sanger
13  c.[1035-3T>C]+[1035-3T>C]   166170127   166170127   T   C   intronic    SCN2A       
16  c.[2994C>T]+[=] 166210776   166210776   C   T   exonic  SCN2A   synonymous SNV  
19  c.[4914T>A]+[4914T>A]   166245230   166245230   T   A   exonic  SCN2A   synonymous SNV  
20  c.[5109C>T]+[=] 166245425   166245425   C   T   exonic  SCN2A   synonymous SNV  
21  c.[5139C>T]+[=] 166848646   166848646   G   A   exonic  SCN1A   synonymous SNV  
22  c.3152_3153insAACCACT   166892841   166892841   -   AGTGGTT exonic  SCN1A   frameshift insertion    TP
23  c.2044-5delT    166898947   166898947   A   -   intronic    SCN1A       
25  c.1530_1531insA 166901684   166901684   -   T   exonic  SCN1A   frameshift insertion    FP
```

**current output**

```
Category    Count
indelindelindelindel        5
A       4
C       7
Ref     1
-       4
G       2
T       6
TCCT        1
```

**desired output**

```
Category    Count
indel        2
```

Comment: your count `{a[$5]++}` is unconditioned.  Also I think you should look for equality not pattern match.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go...

```
$ awk -F'\t' '$5=="-"{count++} 
                  END{print "Category","Count"; 
                      print "indel",count}' file | 
  column -t

Category  Count
indel     2
```

Comment: `print "indel",count+0` so you print 0 instead of a null string when no `-`s present.

Comment: Thank you both very much, I appreciate it :)